# Numeric solve transcendental equation in python or Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numeric

I have a Euler-Bernoulli equation I'm trying to solve where:

```
q(x) = a*x + b + w(x)
```

Euler-Bernoulli equation:

```
E * I * diff(w(x), x, x, x, x) = q(x)
```

I don't really know if this is Transcendental, but I have E, I, a, b and know my integration limits too (0 to H). I have numbers for E, I, a, b and H.

How can I obtain points of w(x),x varying x from 0 to H?

Comment: Are you solving this symbolically or using numerical methods?  This might be more suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm solving symbolic. In math.stackexchange I have no reputation points, so I can't comment my questions and everything is way more difficult.

Comment: Just use `ode45` and solve numerically, the accuracy should be perfectly fine, since you have numbers for your variables.

Comment: ode45 looks just like what I need from the docs. I don't understand the initial conditions vector, what does it mean?

Comment: `ode45` is ill-suited to solve this equation since beam problems are boundary value problems with at least one piece of data at both ends.  `bvp4c` or `bvp5c` are the correct utilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to solve it symbolically, you could, with e.g. [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/):

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
w = symbols('w', cls=Function)
a,b,E,J =  symbols('a b E J')
equ = E*J*diff(w(x),x,4) - a*x -b - w(x)
dsolve(equ, w(x))
# This generates a function that is too generic and too big to copy-paste
# Let's make some assumptions
J = Symbol('J', real=True, positive=True)
E = Symbol('E', real=True, positive=True)
equ = E*J*diff(w(x),x,4) - a*x -b - w(x)
dsolve(equ, w(x))
```

which results in:

```
               -x                 x                                                           
           ───────────       ───────────                                                      
           4 ___ 4 ___       4 ___ 4 ___                                                      
           ╲╱ E ⋅╲╱ J        ╲╱ E ⋅╲╱ J          ⎛     x     ⎞         ⎛     x     ⎞          
w(x) = C₁⋅ℯ            + C₂⋅ℯ            + C₃⋅sin⎜───────────⎟ + C₄⋅cos⎜───────────⎟ - a⋅x - b
                                                 ⎜4 ___ 4 ___⎟         ⎜4 ___ 4 ___⎟          
                                                 ⎝╲╱ E ⋅╲╱ J ⎠         ⎝╲╱ E ⋅╲╱ J ⎠
```

Which you could probably even simplify further, given extra information about your boundary conditions. You'll need them in any case, because you still have 4 unknown coefficients.

Comment: I was solving symbolic because sympy was the only thing I knew, wanted numeric, but now I think I want your answer. How do I make sympy draw stuff like yours? mine draw things way more difficult to read.

Comment: You mean the pretty unicode? If your terminal supports it, enable it with [`pretty_printing()`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a solution using the Symbolic toolbox in Matlab:

```
syms q x w(x) a b E I
q = a*x+b+w(x);
sol = dsolve(E*I*diff(diff(diff(diff(w)))) == q)
sol_part = subs(sol,[E I],[2e5 100]) % etc.
```

You can add the boundary conditions as separate equations to the `dsolve` command, thus forming a system of equations.